# Two way binding of wordcloud data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I want to generate wordcloud using dynamic data using d3,.js with angular 5.
I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-d3-word-cloud
this npm package

```
<div AgWordCloud #word_cloud_chart=ag-word-cloud [wordData]="word_cloud[options]="options">
    </div>
```

My doubt is in any way can I two way bind data here

Comment: Did you mean `[wordData]="word_cloud" [options]="options"` in the code sample?

Comment: I need to implement two way binding for word_cloud array so that workcloud will update as array gets updated

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this situation, the canvas area didn't redraw after the response of the backend. I used the following example https://github.com/alhazmy13/Angular4-word-cloud and I have changed few things and it worked well.

**html**:

```
<div AgWordCloud
     #wordcloudchart=ag-word-cloud
     [wordData]="wordData"
     [options]="wordTagOptions">
</div>
```

**ts-declaration**:

```
wordTagOptions = {};
wordData: Array<AgWordCloudData> = [];
@ViewChild('wordcloudchart', {static: false})
agWordCloudDirective: AgWordCloudDirective;
```

**ts-inside-of-method**:

```
this.auditoriaMacroService.list(filtroAtividade)
  .then(resultado => {
       this.wordData = resultado.map(programa => {

          const size: number = programa.tempo.slice(0, 3).replace(':', '');
                    const word = {size: (programa.texto.toLowerCase() == "total" ? -10 : size), text: programa.texto, color: `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`};
                    return word;

                });

                this.agWordCloudDirective.wordData = this.wordData
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.agWordCloudDirective.update();
                });
            });
```

the result is showed [word-cloud-my-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqve6.png)